# Bad Request "ErrorExecuteSearchStaleData" in Microsoft Graph API - Search for Mails

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, microsoft-graph-mail

We are using Microsoft Graph Search API to search through our O365 emails. Since the search only allows 25 results per request for mails. (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/search-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta#page-search-results)

We figured to work around this by batching our search request like this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$batch
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "url": "/search/query",
            "method": "POST",
            "id": "MyMails-0",
            "body":
            {
                "requests": [
                    {
                        "entityTypes": ["message"],
                        "query":
                        {
                            "query_string":
                            {
                                "query": "some search text"
                            }
                        },
                        "from": 0,
                        "size": 25
                    }
                ]
            },
            "headers":
            {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        },
        {
            "url": "/search/query",
            "method": "POST",
            "id": "MyMails-1",
            "body":
            {
                "requests": [
                    {
                        "entityTypes": ["message"],
                        "query":
                        {
                            "query_string":
                            {
                                "query": "some search text"
                            }
                        },
                        "from": 25,
                        "size": 25
                    }
                ]
            },
            "headers":
            {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        },
        {
            "url": "/search/query",
            "method": "POST",
            "id": "MyMails-2",
            "body":
            {
                "requests": [
                    {
                        "entityTypes": ["message"],
                        "query":
                        {
                            "query_string":
                            {
                                "query": "some search text"
                            }
                        },
                        "from": 50,
                        "size": 25
                    }
                ]
            },
            "headers":
            {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        },
        {
            "url": "/search/query",
            "method": "POST",
            "id": "MyMails-3",
            "body":
            {
                "requests": [
                    {
                        "entityTypes": ["message"],
                        "query":
                        {
                            "query_string":
                            {
                                "query": "some search text"
                            }
                        },
                        "from": 75,
                        "size": 25
                    }
                ]
            },
            "headers":
            {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This works usually well, but in some cases the API returns something like this:

```
{
    "id": "MyMails-2",
    "status": 400,
    "headers":
    {
        "Link": "<https://developer.microsoft-tst.com/en-us/graph/changes?$filterby=beta,RemoveDeprecatedUnderscoreProperty&from=2021-12-01&to=2022-01-01>;rel=\"deprecation\";type=\"text/html\",<https://developer.microsoft-tst.com/en-us/graph/changes?$filterby=beta,RemoveDeprecatedUnderscoreProperty&from=2021-12-01&to=2022-01-01>;rel=\"deprecation\";type=\"text/html\",<https://developer.microsoft-tst.com/en-us/graph/changes?$filterby=beta,RemoveDeprecatedUnderscoreProperty&from=2021-12-01&to=2022-01-01>;rel=\"deprecation\";type=\"text/html\"",
        "Deprecation": "Tue, 14 Dec 2021 23:59:59 GMT",
        "Sunset": "Sat, 31 Dec 2022 23:59:59 GMT",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body":
    {
        "error":
        {
            "code": "BadRequest",
            "message": "\r\n An exception occurred\r\n Lss call failed with status code 400. \"Exchange service returned error ErrorExecuteSearchStaleData: Please reissue the query with rowOffset = 0. The specified rowoffset is '50', but the results are stale.\".",
            "innerError":
            {
                "date": "2022-01-25T09:58:53",
                "request-id": "75def95f-a857-427d-a8b4-ee2792329e87",
                "client-request-id": "75def95f-a857-427d-a8b4-ee2792329e87"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed the deprecation note in the header, however I can't find anything about it. Neither about the actual exception.

What am I missing?

**[workaround]**

Thanks for the hint @user2250152.
This heavily reduced the issue by splitting the request into two requests, while the second is able to request more than 25 mails at a time:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$batch
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "url": "/search/query",
            "method": "POST",
            "id": "MyMails-0",
            "body": {
                "requests": [
                    {
                        "entityTypes": [
                            "message"
                        ],
                        "query": {
                            "query_string": {
                                "query": "some search text"
                            }
                        },
                        "from": 0,
                        "size": 25
                    }
                ]
            },
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        },
        {
            "url": "/search/query",
            "method": "POST",
            "id": "MyMails-1",
            "body": {
                "requests": [
                    {
                        "entityTypes": [
                            "message"
                        ],
                        "query": {
                            "query_string": {
                                "query": "some search text"
                            }
                        },
                        "from": 25,
                        "size": 200
                    }
                ]
            },
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error with stale results can happen time to time.

You can decrease the number of batch requests to reduce a chance that the error with stale results will occur.

For the first page `"from": 0` the max `size` is 25. But for the next page `"from": 25` you can increase the page `size` to 200.

I've tested the search query with `"from": 25` and `"size": 200` and it returns 200 results.

Resources:

[Page search results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/search-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#page-search-results)

Comment: I already tried that. For messages is the maximum size 25: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/search-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta#page-search-results

Comment: @EliaFranke I've tried to set from =25 and size=200 and it returns 200 results. Only for from=25 it returns 25 no matter if you set size > 25

Comment: Interesting. Setting from=1 and size=200 returns more than 25 results. That seems to be a bug, not a feature lol! :) Thanks for the hint!